# How do I reach enclosed chests?

Tags: rogue-legacy

Is it possible, or is this a procedural generation bug?

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Short answer: dwarfism gives you access to secret passages.

Comment: Just gonna point out before if/when this gets locked; rooms in Rogue Legacy aren't procedurally generated. They've all been pre-built ahead of time by the developers. It's the castle/forest/tower/dungeon layout that is generated procedurally, by attaching these pre-built rooms.